# new app still counting against object/tabs

Tags: managed-package, package, security-review

New managed package just passed security review, tried installing into a test org and it still counts against object/tab limits in the org. Also still getting the notice when installing the app: "Salesforce.com Inc. is not the provider of this application and has not conducted any review of it."

Is this just because it is a test org? As far as I know, managed+security review should not being doing this (originally thought it just needed to be a managed package).

Is it because it is a private listing? Don't want to make it public since it is specifically meant for 1 customer.

Do I need to fill out the rest of the listing to 100%?

Do I need to request Aloha status (thought this was deprecated and all managed packages get this now)?

Do I need to push an update/patch so it recognizes the security review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Partner Support:
"We enable Aloha Status on our partners applications that pass security review on the following Friday after they pass"

But they can enable it earlier if you ask.

Comment: Good to know that!